# Flyway Invocation of init method failed

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I'm trying to set up Flyway to work with Spring JPA. I'm stuck at:

`Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgu: name`

Stack trace isn't giving me much more to work with. I have a previous database where many entities have a `name` column. I'm guessing Flyway is having some trouble extracting the existing database schema? I looked trough Spring, Spring Boot, and Flyway docs, but couldn't find anything for this.

I have a PostgreSQL database. Here are the related dependencies from my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1002.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my Flyway configuration in application.properties:

```
flyway.baseline-version=1
flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
flyway.check-location=true
flyway.locations=${MIGPATH}
```

I think locations is correct, because I had a mistake with it earlier and after fixing that, the error message changed. It's a path to a folder with 1 file called `V1__f.sql` - here are its contents:

```
ALTER TABLE category ADD hidden boolean NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE expense ADD details VARCHAR(256);
```

Since the error was related to `name` and my migrations don't concern that field, I'm guessing this error is not caused by the contents of the migration file. In any case I believe the contents of the migration file is correct (my previously existing database + those 2 changes should be compatible with the schema implicitly defined by my JPA entity definitions).

Comment: For a qualified answer we need a bit more information:
- how looks your flyway configuration
- which content have your mysql scripts 

Add the moment it looks that your spring configuration is not correct to setup the flyway bean correct.

Comment: Edited relevant info to OP.

Comment: The value of ${MIGPATH} is important. If it starts with filesystem: than the direcotry must exist and must contain your migration files. If it start with a path it is per default a classpath scan and scripts must be found inside of your classpath.

Comment: It starts with filesystem:/ and the directory contains 1 migration file. It doesn't contain any files representing the current state of the database schema.

Comment: I suspect the issue you are facing has to do with the flyway config in your application.properties file. Try removing the last two config relating to location, everything else seems correct (according to my project setup anyway)